# Vertical align div and float left image

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I give error when float the left image and vertical align not works fine.
I Hope you can help 
I save The code here : http://www.cssdesk.com/ZH7PM

Comment: You really need to give more details. What is your question?

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: The second div is not align center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you design, you want the image to alternate between being on the right and then the left, and similarly for the caption `p` element.

The simplest way is to use CSS tables.  Set the `#wrapper` to use `display: table` with 100% width.

Use `display: table-cell` and width 50% on the two child elements `#left-div` and `#right-div` and then use the `nth-child` selectors to adjust the `text-align` property as needed.

Finally, add the red border to the `p` element and treat it as an inline-block.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  min-height: 214px;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 214px;
}
#wrapper:nth-child(2n+1) #left-div {
  text-align: left
}
#wrapper:nth-child(2n+1) #right-div {
  text-align: right;
}
#wrapper:nth-child(2n+0) #left-div {
  text-align: right;
}
#wrapper:nth-child(2n+0) #right-div {
  text-align: left;
}
#wrapper p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
#left-div {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: initial;
  width: 50%;
  /* IE 7 hack */
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#right-div {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: initial;
  width: 50%;
  /* IE 7 hack */
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-div">
    <img src="http://www.marcocerullo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id="right-div">
    <p><b>1 Streetwear donna</b>
      <br>Piccolo sottotitolo di testo
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="right-div">
    <p><b>2 Streetwear donna</b>
      <br>Piccolo sottotitolo di testo
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="left-div">
    <img src="http://www.marcocerullo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pay attention to the `p` styling, you also need to reset text-align back to left since that property is inherited. All the best!